# How trajectories work on General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames, geodesics

Imagine the trajectory of a particle is given by:
$$
\mathbf{x}(\tau) = x^{\mu} \mathbf{e_{\mu}}
$$
If we want to know the velocity of this vector:
$$
\frac{d \mathbf{x}}{d \tau} = \frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}\mathbf{e}_{\mu} + x^\mu\frac{d \mathbf{e}^\mu}{d \tau}
$$
But the basis itself, depends on $x^\mu$. So:
$$
\frac{d \mathbf{x}}{d \tau} = \frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}\mathbf{e}_{\mu} + x^\mu \dot{x}^\sigma \partial_{\sigma} \mathbf{e}^\mu
$$
$$
\frac{d \mathbf{x}}{d \tau} = \frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}\mathbf{e}_{\mu} + x^\mu \dot{x}^\sigma \Gamma_{\mu\sigma}^\lambda \mathbf e_\lambda
$$
Finally arriving to the equation that describes the velocity of our particle.
$$
\frac{d \mathbf{x}}{d \tau} = \left (\frac{d x^\lambda}{d \tau} + x^\mu \dot{x}^\sigma \Gamma_{\mu\sigma}^\lambda \right )\mathbf{e}_{\lambda}
$$
But, I have some doubts. Is this right? Does the basis, indeed, depend on their own coordinates? How would you explain this intuitively. Would it be useful to define a global frame where basis do not depend on their coordinates? Does this have to be with the principle of relativity?

Comment: Position is not a vector...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position $\mathbf{x}$ is not a vector,
but the position differential $d\mathbf{x}$ is.

$$d\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{e}_\mu(x)\ dx^{\mu} \tag{1}$$

In case of curvilinear coordinates the basis vectors
$\mathbf{e}_\mu(x)$ depend on the coordinates ($x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$).

[image: curvilinear coordinates with basis vectors]

When considering the trajectory of a particle
its coordinates $x^\mu(\tau)$ depend on a parameter $\tau$.
Basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_\mu(x)$ depending on $\tau$ don't make
sense, because the frame and hence the basis vectors are defined
regardless whether there is a particle or not.
So, from (1) you get the velocity simply as
$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}(\tau)}{d\tau}
 = \mathbf{e}_\mu(x)\ \frac{dx^{\mu}(\tau)}{d\tau} \tag{2}$$

> Would it be useful to define a global frame where basis
> do not depend on their coordinates? Does this have to
> be with the principle of relativity?

Of course it would be nice to have a frame
where the basis vectors are independent of the position.
Then you would have cartesian spacetime coordinates
($ct,x,y,z$), constant basis vectors and a constant metric
(the Minkowski metric).
But this is possible only for a flat space.
As soon as gravity is involved, the spacetime becomes curved,
and it is impossible to find a cartesian coordinate frame,
i.e. constant basis vectors.
That is why you need differential geometry in general relativity,
and deal with the basis vectors and the metric depending on the
coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to define coordinates that depend on position, even for flat space. For example, spherical coordinates.

One of the basis vectors is points in the direction of increasing $r$. This is radially outward. It changes direction with position. The other two are similar. They point in the direction of increasing $\theta$ and $\phi$. The trio is mutually perpendicular at any point and always of unit length. But the direction changes for all three.